# Abandoned connection cleanup in mariadb (compared to mysql)?

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

Switching from `mysql-connector` to `mariadb` client library:

What is the equivalent of the mysql class `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkedShutdown()`?

If there is any at all?
(I'm also using `hikari` connection pool).

Comment: What is the need exactly? hikari will clean up connection kindly, and forcing connections after some time if still used using connection.abort() ( https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.java#L207)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an equivalent, it looks like this feature was not migrated to Maria DB. It would be more prudent to fix the connection leak in the application instead.

As explained by HikariCP pool author in [this message](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/hikari-cp/zBKo96xoHXI/80hSknD7zi4J), this feature of force closing abandoned connections has a number of problems:

> Yes, we have considered it (removing abandoned connections), but ultimately we decided to pass.  The problem with closing leaked connections is several fold.  Some thread is possibly using that connection, and its going to blow-up (in production) somewhere if we close it.  Or nothing is using that connection, and closing it has no negative impact, but now we've just covered up a leak that will cause constant cycling of connections in the pool.
>
> Applications are responsible for cleaning up resources.  Java developers tend to get lazy compared to C/C++ programmers.  This is leak just like a memory leak, and both can and rightfully should eventually kill your application.  How else would you 1) know a problem exist, and 2) be motivated to track it down and fix it.
>
> We do appreciate all input, even if not adopted.  In this case, users looking for a library to defensively cover-up coding errors should probably look to tomcat-jdbc.
>
> Note, leak detection can be run in production, and can be enabled at runtime through a JMX console, so there's not a lot of justification for adding proactive connection reclamation.

Comment: So there is no way I can forcibly close abandoned connections?

Comment: @membersound I'm not aware of how to do it properly. Let me know if you find a way to do it cleanly and without risking something blowing up. You may try using Tomcat `jdbc-pool` with `removeAbandoned` flag but it may blow up your application if it removes the connection too early.

Comment: Sounds like a reason to avoid connection pooling, at least with Java.